# How do I control the namespace of a closure in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Tests\Unit\BaseUnitTestCase::assertMockedMethodRuns() must be an
>   instance of Tests\Unit\Closure, instance of Closure given

When passing a closure to my `assertMockedMethodRuns` method

BaseUnitTestCase

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;

class BaseUnitTestCase extends TestCase
{
    public function assertMockedMethodRuns(Closure $code)
    {
        try {
            $code($this);
        } catch (\Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException $e) {
            $this->assertTrue(False, "Mocked method did not run");
        }
    }
}
```

Routes Test (where I call `assertMockedMethodRuns`)

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

class RoutesTest extends BaseUnitTestCase
{
    public function testGetPostList()
    {
        $mockPostController = \Mockery::mock('PostController');
        $mockPostController->shouldReceive('index')->once();
        $this->app->instance('PostController', $mockPostController);
        $this->assertMockedMethodRuns(function() { 
            $this->call('GET','/post');
        });
    }
}
```

TestCase (Where BaseTestCase inherits from)

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, DatabaseMigrations;
}
```

It seems like the closure being passed to `assertMockedMethodRuns`  does not have the proper namespace. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing and reversed slash to tell PHP the `Closure` class is to be search in the global namespace :

```
public function assertMockedMethodRuns(\Closure $code)
```

Comment: Ah, I could have sworn I tried that before asking this.

Comment: It's not catching the exception now though. A \Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException still gets thrown. Do you see anything wrong with the way the `assertMockedMethodRuns` method is written?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Illuminate unit testing (I use PHPUnit). I don't see anything suspicious. However I'm not sure what is the intended behavior of your closure function. Should it throw the exception or not ?

Comment: Illuminate's TestCase class inherits from PHPUnit's TestCase class, so it shouldn't be that far off. The point of my function is to assert that the `\Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException` is not called and if it is, the test will fail rather than throw an error like it's currently doing.

Comment: I've asked this as a separate question if you want to look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977266/why-does-try-catch-not-catch-errors-thrown-by-laravel-testcases-call-method But I'm beginning to think this is something specific to either laravel or Mockery